# Android Studio With Flutter Update Has Caused an Indexing Loop

Tags: android-studio, dart, flutter

I did an android studio update and updated flutter and now the IDE is stuck in an indexing loop. At the bottom center it keeps flashing 'Updating Indexes...' and my projects `projectName.iml` file keeps flashing between being a file icon and a folder with a green dot icon. Also each file error indicator flashes between the green check to the eye icon.

Not Indexing State Icon: [image: Folder Icon]
Indexing State Icon: [image: File Icon]

I've invalidated the caches and restarted several times and every flutter project is having this same issue. When the update completed I got a flutter notification that reads:

> **Flutter module type updated**
>   Converted from 'WEB_MODULE' to 'JAVA_MODULE'

[image: Flutter module type updated]

I'm able to continue work on the project and launch the application in the emulator without any problems, it's just distracting having this constant flashing on the screen. Anyone else having this problem and found a solution?

---

**Flutter Plugin:**
Version: 23.0.2

**Flutter SDK Version:**
Flutter 0.2.3 • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git Framework • revision 5a58b36e36 (2 weeks ago) • 2018-03-13 13:20:13 -0700 Engine • revision e61bb9ac3a Tools • Dart 2.0.0-dev.35.flutter-290c576264

**Dart Plugin:**
Version: 173.4700

**Dart SDK:**
Path: ~/dev_mobile/flutterSDK/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk
Version: 2.0.0-edge.***cc5fe0

**Coverage Plugin:**
Version: 173.4301.25

**Android Studio:**
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to address this problem by adding

```
<option name="ALLOW_USER_CONFIGURATION" value="false" />
```

to my `project_android.iml` file. Once adding this line, the reindexing loop stopped and it has not even after several days of working and restarting Android Studio. Found the solution in a comment by stevemessick here https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/1735 as per [Günter Zöchbauer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/217408/g%C3%BCnter-z%C3%B6chbauer) link reference in the response above.

Comment: Works! In my case the .iml file then looks like this: 
`<facet type="android" name="Android"> 
<configuration> 
<option name="ALLOW_USER_CONFIGURATION" value="false" /> <option name="UPDATE_PROPERTY_FILES" value="true" /> </configuration> 
</facet>`

Comment: mine already have this line and still indexing... android studio is the shittiest IDE i've ever downloaded

Answer (score 56):

I found this comment in an android studio bug and it fixed it for me:

"File -> invalidating caches and restart"

Comment: This fixed a similar issue for me. I don't know what Flutter is, but my Android Studio kept reindexing and became pretty useless.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/2017
https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/1735
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15973

Plugin version 23 was supposed to fix that, but it seems it hasn't.

Comment: Thank you for providing these. I was able to find a fix in one of the links you provided. I have added the details in an answer here.

Answer (score 1):

in my case, adding

```
<option name="ALLOW_USER_CONFIGURATION" value="false" />
```

didn't solve the problem, I also noticed this loop happens just with activities linked to a layout XML file!

Answer (score 0):

Neither invalidate cache nor downgrading Android Studio to 3.1 from 3.1.4 worked (and the "ALLOW_USER_CONFIGURATION" line was already on the IML). 
I fixed the error by deleting the project and re-cloning / reloading it again on Android Studio.

Comment: Till when will you repeat the process. I face this issue in almost all the projects. Shall I delete them, re-clone and reload them again???